# Export SQL table to XML file with datatype included

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

I am trying to export SQL table to XML file with SQL datatype included and adding some nodes as the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="SHIFT-JIS" standalone="yes"?>
<root><X_PO_NO>GV11556</X_PO_NO><DATABASE><PO><TBL_PO_H X_PO_NO="GV11556"><DATA><X_PO_NO TYPE="200" LENGTH="13">GV11556</X_PO_NO></DATA></TBL_PO_H><TBL_PO_M X_PO_NO="GV11556"><DATA><X_PO_NO TYPE="200" LENGTH="13">GV11556</X_PO_NO><X_PO_LINE_NO TYPE="3" LENGTH="4">1</X_PO_LINE_NO></DATA></TBL_PO_M></PO></DATABASE></root>
```

but when I used

```
private void WriteXmlToFile(DataSet thisDataSet, string fileName)
            {
                if (thisDataSet == null)
                {
                    return;
                }

                // Create a file name to write to.
                string filename = fileName;

                // Create the FileStream to write with.
                System.IO.FileStream myFileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(filename, System.IO.FileMode.Create);

                // Create an XmlTextWriter with the fileStream.
                System.Xml.XmlTextWriter myXmlWriter =
                new System.Xml.XmlTextWriter(myFileStream, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("SHIFT-JIS"));

                // Write to the file with the WriteXml method.
                thisDataSet.WriteXml(myXmlWriter);
                myXmlWriter.Close();
            }
```

Then call method :

```
 WriteXmlToFile(dataset, "FileName");
```

The output XML like below:

```
<DATA><TBL_PO_H><X_PO_NO>GV11556</X_PO_NO></TBL_PO_H><TBL_PO_M><X_PO_NO>GV11556</X_PO_NO><X_PO_LINE_NO>1</X_PO_LINE_NO></TBL_PO_M></DATA>
```

It only exported XML file without Datatype. How to do this. I am new C# and SQL

Comment: Update your **dataset**

Comment: SELECT *
  FROM [_TBL_PO_H] where X_PO_NO='GV00048'
 FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS ABSENT , ROOT ('root')   , No option for including data type

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you are doing here... If I see this correctly, you are using a DataSet's implicit `WriteXml()`. Doing so, you have not much influence on the way the XML is looking. You can include the schema, but this is something else... Why is there a DataSet involved at all? You are calling the XML directly from your database... Why don't you place this within an `XmlDocument`, modify it to your needs and write this out?

Comment: My question is ow to output SQL table to XML file that include the data type. You help help me in C# or in SQL store procedure. I tried 2 ways but unsuccessful.

Comment: @user3035133 Can u update  **[_TBL_PO_H]**  table with data and design